# Edit data set's specific column with script, according to arguments

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh

I am trying to create a bash script that does what the following example does:

Before edit:

```
#id/name/surname/age
4|Rebecca|Jones|24
5|Nick|Simmons|31
```

Now when i run the script i want to determine with the ID which row will change, and with another argument what column in this row.
After edit:

```
./script.sh 4 2 Rachel #we are changing the second column in row with ID=4 
#id/name/surname/age
4|Rachel|Jones|24
5|Nick|Simmons|31
```

Later i want to save by overwriting the existing .txt

Thanks in advance for any help!

---

By using the solution provided by Bohah the outcome on the terminal is the following:

```
Usage: gawk [POSIX or GNU style options] -f progfile [--] file ...
Usage: gawk [POSIX or GNU style options] [--] 'program' file ...
POSIX options:      GNU long options: (standard)
    -f progfile     --file=progfile
    -F fs           --field-separator=fs
    -v var=val      --assign=var=val
Short options:      GNU long options: (extensions)
    -b          --characters-as-bytes
    -c          --traditional
    -C          --copyright
    -d[file]        --dump-variables[=file]
    -e 'program-text'   --source='program-text'
    -E file         --exec=file
    -g          --gen-pot
    -h          --help
    -L [fatal]      --lint[=fatal]
    -n          --non-decimal-data
    -N          --use-lc-numeric
    -O          --optimize
    -p[file]        --profile[=file]
    -P          --posix
    -r          --re-interval
    -S          --sandbox
    -t          --lint-old
    -V          --version

 To report bugs, see node `Bugs' in `gawk.info', which is
section `Reporting Problems and Bugs' in the printed version.

gawk is a pattern scanning and processing language.
By default it reads standard input and writes standard output.

 Examples:
    gawk '{ sum += $1 }; END { print sum }' file
    gawk -F: '{ print $1 }' /etc/passwd
```

Comment: The `id` column could be modified too ?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a free code writing service. If you have attempted to write something and have some difficulties, then show what you have done and ask a specific question.
Refer to [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for tips. If you just want free work done then StackOverflow isn't the place for such requests.
Learn to write your code yourself or pay someone to write it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With sed:

```
sed -i "/^$1|/s/|\([^|]*\)/|$3/$(( $2-1 ))" file.txt
```

- `/^$1|/`: search for lines that match the first argument value passed to the script
- `s`: substitution command
- `|\([^|]*\)`: search for string containing `|` followed by any non-pipe character. Using brackets, this last string is captured for to come backreference
- `|$3` substitute previous pattern with `|` followed by the third  argument value
- `$(( $2-1 ))`: arithmetic expansion to decrement the value of the second argument. This modifier placed at the end of the substitution command specify which occurrence of the pattern `|\([^|]*\)` will be replaced

Comment: I have zero knowledge regarding `sed`...if you could break that down for me i would be pleased!

Answer (score 1):

I'd use GNU Awk (wrapped into a shell script if needed):

```
gawk\
 -v key=4\
 -v col=2\
 -v val='Rachel'\
 -i inplace\
 'BEGIN { FS = "|"; OFS="|" } $1 == key { $(col) = val } { print }'\
  ~/tmp/filename.txt
```

Comment: That sadly comes up with a weird outcome...i don't have that much experience and i can't 'translate' it... I edited the original post, and embeded the outcome in there! Thank you for your support!

Comment: @MrDiaman - from the output you posted, it looks as if your version of GAWK might be old enough that it doesn't include `-i inplace`. Just drop that option and try this solution using a temporary file instead. A very basic wrapper will take care of this for you. If you have trouble writing the wrapper, please include your attempt in a new question.